# Creating a pdf from a string with html content with NodeJS

Tags: html, node.js, pdf, pdf-generation

I need to create an api who will recieve a json with at least 3 strings, header, content of the file and the footer
i've searched over the web for a library or an api who help me with that but everything i've found is or too simple or too expensive.
i have already created the part who will recieve the json and the part who will send it (sending the file via base64 encoding) using an already downloaded pdf file

but i need a library to create the pdf with the header and footer on every page.

anyone has some experience doing this on nodejs?

Comment: I'm using html-pdf and it works just fine. It has some options for header and footer too. https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf

Comment: @Molda Thanks!, i'll give it a look.

Comment: the proposed `html-pdf` uses the long deprecated phantomJS, there's `better-html-pdf` on npm that uses puppeteer and is more customizable. https://github.com/0tii/html-to-pdf